# How can I slide google map?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, webmatrix

I have solved my problem here

[do I need getJson at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550464/do-i-need-getjson-at-all/12550543#12550543)

The map is reloaded everytime I click a place name that I made as a hyperlink. However, I don't like this kind of reloading effect, I would like the map to *move*, which looks like when I am dragging my mouse slowly to view a different place. That is, if I click a link of a place on my browser client (i located it as a table data displayed in `<table>`), the map will *slide* to display the new place, not reload the whole region.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but, if you are not reloading your page (in which case you can't achieve this effect) you should use the `panTo()` method instead of `setCenter()` to achieve a smooth sliding effect.